# Radio buttons all active at once when I load the page in Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="form-row">
                            <div class="column">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary active" for="visualContagi">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="visualContagi" checked> Contagi
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="visualGuariti">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="visualGuariti" checked> Guariti
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="visualDecessi">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="visualDecessi" checked> Decessi
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="visualRicoveri">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="visualRicoveri" checked> Ricoveri
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="visualTotPos">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="visualTotPos" checked> Totale Positivi
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Hi, I have this radio button group as part of a form. The problem is that the buttons all get the "active" class applied to them when I load the webpage. I haven't written any javascript, it's just bootstrap, and this CSS applied to remove the outline when I click on the buttons:

```css
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

I'm using the latest version of Firefox on macOS.

Comment: because all of ```input type="radio"``` has `checked` attribute. Just remove it and leave one (if you need some radio to be checked by default) or remove them at all.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, I just removed the "active" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am noticing is that each of your `<input type="radio"` elements have the `checked` attribute attatched to them. If you remove that, then it should be fixed. I hope this helps!